# Nested resolve not returning properly with UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building an App with nested states using UI-Router.

So far the first state resolves OK and returns an array of objects (fair) which displays on the frontend.

```
$stateProvider.state('berliner', {
  url: '/berlinerliste/',
  views: {
    'header': {   
      templateUrl: 'header.htm'   
    },
    'main':{    
      templateUrl: 'bl2017.htm'    
    }
  },
  params : {search: 'Berliner 2017'},
  resolve: {
    fair: function(SearchService, $stateParams) {
      return SearchService.getAllExhibitors($stateParams.search);
    }
  }
})

$stateProvider.state('berliner.exhibitor', {
  url: '/berlinerliste/{id}', 
  views: {
    'header': {   
      templateUrl: 'header.htm'  
    },
    'main':{ 
      component: 'exhibitor'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    exhibitor: function($stateParams, fair) {
      return $filter("filter")(fair, {'slug':$stateParams.id}, true);
    }
  }
})
```

When I click on one of the objects though, nothing happens.

The nested state resolve should take the `fair` array and filter out the object which `'slug':$stateParams.id`.

This is the part on the `templateUrl: 'bl2017.htm'` where I assign the `id` parameter to the nested state:

```
<article ng-repeat="exhibitor in datafairs" ui-sref="exhibitor({ id: exhibitor.slug })" >
```

Oh, and the nested state has a component binded to it:

```
.component('exhibitor', {
  bindings: { exhibitor: '<' },
  templateUrl: 'exhibitor.htm',
})
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Try injecting fair in the exhibitor function?

Comment: @Vivz no errors! I click and nothing happens. I injected the fair into the function now, will edit code.

Comment: Change ur ui-sref to  ui-sref="berliner.exhibitor({ id: exhibitor.slug })"

Comment: Is it working now?